# Navigation after async operation using react and redux/thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a simple React app and I wish to have a button that when click going to some  API and fetch some data and then show it in a new screen. However, I would not like the route my app to the other screen only until the API returned.

There are several solutions for this and I am not sure which are the best one.

For example, to achieve this when using thunk, I can just navigate inside my action when the API call was done successfully.

But what is the right way of doing this? Or is doing it via the action is the right way ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't do it in the action, I'd return when the action is done successfully, and let it be handled in the component.

The reason for this is that you might want to run multiple actions, but if you do the navigation in the action then you could end up navigating away before other actions dispatch with the data you want them to.

Also, if you want to navigate in your actions using React Router for example, then you'll have to keep passing the `history` object to your actions, which can get messy.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but then if you let the component handled it, how would you suggest of letting the component handle it? when the component will trigger the navigation?

Comment: Also what will happens if you have several places which you would like to to allow to navigate to that specific screen which needs that data, you will need that any parent component will somehow recieve that the action was done and navigate. this sounds to me like a problem but you will need to change that on every component you theroaticlly can navigate that location.

Comment: You can return a promise from the action. It depends on your app layout I guess, but you could just navigate based on whether the data is in the store or not.